# serving private javascript files on express

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is probably going to be really embarrassing. I have file structure as follows.

[image]

I am following the code at https://github.com/Jastor11/node-express-firebase-voting-app/blob/master/views/home.ejs

This project also uses express but with ejs instead of hbs. I don't think that should be relevant though.

From login.hbs in views folder I am doing this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/firebaseAuth.js"></script>
```

So I need to get the script from view/js/firebaseAuth.js.
Both login.hbs and js folder are in the view folder.

Since my login.hbs is in views folder already, I thought this would work.

On my dev machine, the login page is served at
http://localhost:4000/login

The file fails to load from the path with 404
http://localhost:4000/js/firebaseAuth.js

The path above is not right. It was meant to be relative path. I do not want to specify a public path for this js file. Otherwise I would have kept it in a public folder.

How do I include this js file?
I have also tried

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/firebaseAuth.js"></script>
```

Comment: If it's not in the `public` folder,  your server won't serve it.

Comment: https://github.com/Jastor11/node-express-firebase-voting-app/blob/master/views/home.ejs

This does with

     <script src="js/firebaseAuth.js"></script>

Has the exact same directory structure.

Comment: They configure the server to serve `views/` (which is probably a bad idea). https://github.com/Jastor11/node-express-firebase-voting-app/blob/master/server.js#L24-L25

Comment: I wonder if it has to do with you serving your page at `/login` instead of the root?

Comment: SLaks and Katamari, thank you! I totally missed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In line 24 of the `server.js` file, you will notice the following code

```
// We also want to send css, images, and other static files
app.use(express.static('views'))
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views')
```

This is allowing the server to show any files that are in the views directory, including the `views/js/firebaseAuth.js` file.